# SSRS Syntax Error when trying to use Parameter in table name and Where Clause

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm attempting to create a report that needs 2 parameters in SSRS.  One of them will be used to change the table selected each time the query is run. The tables have years in them (e.g. TA_2014) and depending on the year they'd like to see, they'll need to see a different table.  The second parameter is just a term, though I don't believe it is giving me the issue.

My query looks like this in SSRS

```
="SELECT
p.ID,
p.LAST_NAME + ', ' + p.FIRST_NAME AS 'STUDENT_NAME',
ta.TA_TERM_AMOUNT
FROM
PERSON p,
TA_" & Parameters!pYear.Value & " ta
WHERE
p.ID = SUBSTRING(ta.TA_" & Parameters!pYear.Value & "_ID,1,7)
AND ta.TA_" & Parameters!pYear.Value & "_ID LIKE '%PELL%'
AND ta.TA_TERM_MANUAL_CHG = 'Y'
AND RIGHT(ta.TA_" & Parameters!pYear.Value & "_ID,6) = @pTerm
ORDER BY
STUDENT_NAME"
```

I'm getting a syntax error near ','

When I take out the " & Parameters!pYear.Value & " and hard code in a year, like 2014 for example, the report runs fine.  I have other reports where I've done this exact thing for tables, but I can't get it to work now.  I'm clearly missing something.  I've been comparing my older reports for weeks now and I'm not seeing why the older reports work and the new ones do not.  Any idea?

Comment: Try checking a) the datatype and b) the available values for parameter `pYear` in your new report, compared with the older reports, and also check whether the older reports were using ...`pYear.Label` rather than ...`pYear.Value`. If that doesn't reveal the problem, try replacing the existing query with a relatively simple expression (such as `select getdate()`) and include output that evaluates the expression `"TA_" & Parameters!pYear.Value & " ta"`.

Comment: a) datatypes are all the same
b) available values are the same

It is using pYear.Value.  I even tried copy/pasting from the other report.

Comment: Use a profiler trace to find out what sql query is being executed by your report.

Comment: Also try removing the single quotes from  AS 'STUDENT_NAME',

Comment: Removing the quotes didn't help, and I've never used a profiler.  I'm looking it up to figure it out.  And @MarkBannister, I'm not sure what you mean by "include output that evaluates the expression..."

Comment: @MarkBannister Even a very simple query gives a syntax error.

    SELECT
    GETDATE()
    FROM
    TA_" & Parameters!pYear.Value

Returns "Incorrect syntax near ')' "

Comment: Not `SELECT GETDATE() FROM TA_" & Parameters!pYear.Value` - **just** `SELECT GETDATE()`. (Do this in a copy of your existing report).  Include output that evaluates and displays the result of the expression `"TA_" & Parameters!pYear.Value & " ta"`

Comment: @MarkBannister I did `SELECT GETDATE()` and added a field to the report that just shows `"TA_" & Parameters!pYear.Value & " ta"`.  Which evaluated to `TA_2014 ta` when 2014 was selected, which is what I want.  So the parameter is (apparently) working as intended.

Comment: Now try building your query up a line at time, to find which line is causing the error.

Comment: @MarkBannister It immediately breaks down when the `Parameter!pYear.Value` is inserted into the query.

Comment: Try changing `SELECT GETDATE()` to `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TA_2014` - if it runs, then try changing it to `="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TA_" & Parameters!pYear.Value` and see whether that runs.

Comment: @MarkBannister The count runs fine.  Breaks when you put the parameter in there.  There's got to be something different between the older reports and the new ones.  I can't figure out what it is for the life of me.

Comment: Try changing `="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TA_" & Parameters!pYear.Value` to `="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TA_" & 2014` if the parameter's datatype is numeric - enclose the `2014` in `"`s if it's a string - and try again.

Comment: Syntax error for `="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TA_" & 2014` and `="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TA_" & "2014"`

Comment: @MarkBannister I got in contact with a support guy from a company I work with and he VM'd into our server, wrote the same thing, and it works for him.  So...iunno.

Comment: You really need to run a profiler trace.   Learning to use profiler will be invaluable throughout your career as a sql developer.